# Java Spring application Database triggers auditing - how to provide the right user that made the change

Tags: java, database, spring, triggers, audit

We are developing a new web application. one of the most basic requirement is to audit all entities changes into a separate table.

We would like to use DB triggers for that purpose.

We use MySQL as our RDMBS.

The problem we now foresee is that whenever a trigger is pulled, and insert a new entry for the DB, it cant possibly know the (applicative) user that made the change. (all users have different ids, but spring uses a single user account for the db manipulations.)

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: have you resolve this issue? I am facing the same issue. Please share your solution.

Comment: @stanicmail - check out my answer

Answer (score 1):

We resolved the issue by adding a field to all tables that are being audited of the userId, and on each CRUD operation we made it mandatory to provide it. (for system business logic we use id=0). this way our audit table are being populated with the id itself to be monitored.

Comment: How about delete trigger? Are you able to capture the user id?

Comment: We do not delete any data :)